# Get accurate times from serial port without RTC

Tags: time, serial-port, embedded

I have a standalone box without an RTC. It does have a millisecond tick timer though, which is accurate.

I am sending, via a USB UART port to a Windows machine. I can also write to the box via the same way from the Windows machine.

When I receive the bytes sent by the box via the serial port, there is a noticable delay. That delay is something like 16ms, and that is not something that can be fixed on Windows.

So, given data sent from the box, how can I, the Windows machine, know what exact millisecond the box sent it, despite the delay, syncing it to a real timestamp?

I could send the current milliseconds that the box counts with the data, but then that would be outdated by the time it is received.

For example:

- at 10ms, the box sends data.
- the Windows machine receives the data 20ms later due to delay or whatever.
- Windows then has to assume the box sent the data at 30ms, but it should be 10ms.

I tried sending the current box ms on each data sending, but then I do not know how much time has passed.

Comment: Does your box use a USB module, or is there a serial interface involved? In the latter case the delay is caused by the transmission time and depends on the number of bytes and the baud rate.

Comment: All common desktop OS let their applications run in time slices. Commonly the resolution is 10ms, so the accuracy is in that range. Usually you cannot do anything about this.

Comment: There are several protocols that solved the problem of synchronizing the "time" of two systems. You might want to do some research, for example "Euroradio+" for European railways.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your messages. That is correct. From my research, yes, hence why I asked how to do this even with those uncertain delays. Thank for the sync method. I'll have a look!

Comment: Since Windows is not an RTOS, there is no reliable way of doing this.  Moreover if the interface is via a USB/serial bridge, USB is not real-time capable either, Ince it is a master-slave simplex bus emulating a peer_to-peer duplex connection.  In either case the windows USB and serial driver stacks are buffered in such a way that the application level need not be notified of data availability immediately.  All that is out of your control.  Tom V' s solution may work, most of the time, but it will not be hard-realtime deterministic.

Comment: "_but then I do not know how much time has passed_" - it is not clear to me what you mean by that - passed since when?  That is the solution to your problem, so in that sense this is an X-Y problem, you should be asking about how to make that work, because your solution won't work.

Comment: There's a lot of latency and timeout settings in the port level. These can be tweaked through for example Windows API functions to reduce lag. Also no matter how you do it, you must compensate for the transmission time of the data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to send a message and reply and count the total time for the two-way round trip, and then subtract half of it.

Eg:

- clockless box sends "what time is it?" message and records the value of its tick counter when it sends the message as #1234.
- Host sends back "it's 11:59:59.999".
- clockless box receives this message when its tick counter says #1250.

The clockless box knows that the time 11:59:59.999 equates to somewhere between tick #1234 and tick #1250.

The clockless box assumes that 11:59:59.999 equates to half-way between these ticks, so it adjusts its software RTC to make tick #1242 equals 11:59:59.999.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds pretty neat. Do you think it could be improved by doing this multiple times to fine tune the time, or is that redundant?

Comment: It depends what is causing the delay.  If it is variable then averaging may help.  Also if you know that it is slower in one direction than the other then you can take that into account.

Comment: The assumption that the turn-around time is symmetrical is perhaps a big leap.  Especially if the interface is a USB-Serial bridge.  It would be an interesting experiment, but you would need an implementation with a reference clock in order to prove that one without a reference is valid.  And that may change depending on drivers, Windows version and PC hardware for example.

Comment: @Steamgamer An average will not help you.  If that were necessary, it implies that the delay is variable and non-deterministic.  On arrival of data to be time-stamped, the mean delay might be considerably different than the instantaneous delay, so would be misleading.  The issue is not really the delay, but the jitter.  In the userspace, even without the intrinsic stack delay, a process may be pre-mpted and not scheduled for an undefined length of time, contributing to the timing uncertainty.  The only deterministic solution may be to write your own device driver in kernel space.